# An internal, Windows 7 installed drive fails to boot after transforming into external drive

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, boot

I have installed Windows 7 to my HDD. I also have Ubuntu 14.04 on another partition on the same drive. During boot, via GRUB, I select which one I want to load.

Recently, I upgraded my HDD to SSD. I bought a HDD cover for the old drive. As I rarely use Windows, i only installed Linux distro to my SSD. However, as i sometimes need to use Windows, I thought, it might be great to boot it from the external drive. So, i gave the boot priority to USB port. But i encountered a problem: Windows detects a hardware change, and fails to load. However, the Ubuntu 14.04 at the external drive seamlessly boots... How can i fix the problem?

(I can load the repair module of Windows 7.)

Comment: Did you try disabling secure boot in BIOS?